# Should there be a 'migrate to hsm' close reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, migration, moderation

We currently have a possibility to migrate to meta, physics.SE and stats.SE. Shouldn't there be a possibility too to migrate questions to [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)? I think this is appropriate, since there are quite a few of questions asked here that might fit better at hsm than here.

Comment: And beta sites aren't going to be included in the default migration target list anyway.

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18695/moving-question-to-stack-overflow

Comment: Assuming the Question is on-topic for both sites (and I would not be the best judge for HSM given my limited participation), it would ideally be at the OP's discretion after being informed about HSM to submit a custom flag for moderator migration.  Once there are useful Comments, not to mention Answers, we should discourage self-deletion and reposting.